# Power Apps visual for Power BI SSO issues

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerbi-embedded, powerapps-canvas

We are trying to embed the power bi report using power BI client,

We have requirement to embed a Power Bi report in the Teams Personal App, Create a personal tab for MS Teams

When  try to use power apps visuals in the report, the Power apps asks to sign in. The SSO seems to work only in Teams Browser client but not Teams Desktop client .
[Power Bi report embed in Teams Personal tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF3c0.png)

Can we achieve SSO for power apps in such scenarios, the other issue is the signin button does not show any pop up for sign in, it might be because the Teams Iframe is blocking the  pop ups.

Comment: You can use SSO in Teams at runtime: Your tab app interacts with Azure AD at runtime for one-time authentication and authorization for your app users.
Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview#sso-in-teams-at-runtime

Comment: Refer this-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-organization-app

Comment: There is no problem for power bi report, but it is with power apps visuals

Comment: Please have look into this-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-portal-authentication
Hope it's helpful.